# mysql query select from one table such that its column's values are not present in the same column's values in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables: A, and B.

A has columns id, alpha, blabla, moreblabla, with primary key id.
B has columns id, alpha, beta, somemoreblabla, with primary key (id, alpha)

I need to select all those A.id's, for which its A.alpha is not present in any of the B.alpha's respective to every B.id = A.id

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear. Do you want all A.alpha's that are not in any B.alpha? In that case a simple query like this is enough:

```
Select A.id from A where A.alpha NOT IN (Select B.alpha from B);
```

If you want to select all ID's from A that have a counterpart (an equal ID) in B but where the alpha between A and B are different it is a bit more work:

```
SELECT A.id FROM A
INNER JOIN B on A.id = B.id
WHERE A.alpha != B.alpha
```

Consider the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`alpha` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `B` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`alpha` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

With inserts:

```
insert into A set id = 1, alpha = 'a';
insert into A set id = 2, alpha = 'b';
insert into B set id = 1, alpha = 'a';
insert into B set id = 2, alpha = 'a';
```

If you run the query with the join your result will be:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
+----+
```

This is since ID 2 in A has a different alpha than ID 2 in B.

EDIT:

It just occurred to me that you might even mean that every A.id can occur in B multiple times. If that is what can happen you need a different approach again. Lets assume the same insert as before with an addition:

```
insert into A set id = 1, alpha = 'a';
insert into A set id = 2, alpha = 'b';
insert into B set id = 1, alpha = 'a';
insert into B set id = 2, alpha = 'a';

insert into B set id = 2, alpha = 'b'; <- important since there is now a 2nd 2 in B that should ensure that the record with ID 2 from A should not be returned.

insert into A set id = 3, alpha = 'c';
insert into B set id = 3, alpha = 'x'; <-- only ID 3 should now be returned due to the situation above
```

Our tables now look like so:

```
A
+----+-------+
| id | alpha |
+----+-------+
|  1 | a     |
|  2 | b     |
|  3 | c     |
+----+-------+

B
+----+-------+
| id | alpha |
+----+-------+
|  1 | a     |
|  2 | a     |
|  2 | b     |
|  3 | x     |
+----+-------+
```

If this is your case the following query will do the trick:

```
select A.id 
FROM A where A.alpha NOT IN (
    select B.alpha FROM B where B.id = A.id
);
```

Comment: I want to select all ID's from A that have a counterpart (an equal ID) in B but where the alpha in A is not in any of the respective alphas in B for that equal ID.
To be more clear, suppose Table A has (1,a),(2,b), (3,c) and Table B has (1,a), (1,b), 1,c),(2,a), (2,c), (2,d), (2,e), (3,a), (3,b) then it should return '2', because the alpha of 2 in A, that is, 'b', is not equal to any of the alphas (a, c, d) of the same id 2, in B.

Comment: Than the last part of my answer should help you.

Comment: the last part of your answer will return all of 1, 2, and 3, because there does exist some records in B where A.id = B.id and A.alpha != B.alpha. Which is not what I want. I only want those id's for which the A.alpha is equal to none of the B.alpha's for the same id in A and B

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.id
FROM
A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN B  ON A.id = B.id AND B.alpha = A.alpha
where B.alpha IS NULL
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c17b4/4) is SQL Fiddle

This will be the fastest query,better than `The marked Answer` in terms of query optimization.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT A.id
        FROM
        A 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN B  ON A.id = B.id AND B.alpha = A.alpha
        where B.alpha IS NULL
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c17b4/5) is the output : [image]

```
EXPLAIN select A.id 
FROM A where A.alpha NOT IN (
    select B.alpha FROM B where B.id = A.id
)
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c17b4/8) is the `EXPLAIN` of `Marked answer`.

[image]

You can see the DIFFERENCE.

> `SIMPLE` VS `PRIMARY`
>
> `SIMPLE` VS `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!

Comment: I have edited my answer, i think .pls Let me ur thoughts on this .(There was an edit in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

`Select A.id from table_A where A.alpha NOT IN (Select B.alpha from table_B);`
The Sub-query will return a table with all the records of B.alpha from table_B.
And say it returns 1 to 5 records as result.
And say your table table_A has 1 to 10 records in A.alpha
Now your parent query will check for records in table table_A for field A.alpha which do not belongs to B.alpha (using `NOT IN`)
Hence the expected result is 6 to 10 as result.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL `NOT IN`
Try this query :-

```
select id from a where a.id NOT IN (select id from b)
```